# Cannot push data through a service via HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

I created a `MessageService` that I push data into which is then read by my `app.main` to display those messages to the user.  When I use this service in a component it works fine.  What I want to do is move that up to the `HttpInterceptor` level which will monitor all `HttpResponse` for server messages and push them into the service for user display.

Here is my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
  private successMessageList = new Subject<string>();
  successMessages$ = this.successMessageList.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  addSuccessMsg(msg: string) {
    this.setMsgs(this.successMessageList, msg);
  }

  private setMsgs(privMsgArray: Subject<string>, newMsgs: any) {
    let messages = [];
    messages.push(newMsgs);

    messages.forEach(message => privMsgArray.next(message));
    console.log(this.successMessageList);
  }
}
```

Here is my HttpInterceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttp implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          if(event.body['successMsg']) {
             this.messageService.addSuccessMsg(event.body['successMsg']);
          }
        }
      })
  }
}
```

This is my `app.main` which reads the data

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  successMessages = [];

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.messageService.successMessages$.subscribe(
      message => {
        console.log(message);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.successMessages.push(message);
        });
      });
  }
}
```

With some console statements I can see that data is getting into the `messageService.setMsgs(...)` private method correctly but it's never reaching my `app.main` like it does when I send messages via components.  There are no error messages or anything, it just doesn't work.

One thing I did notice is in the `MessageService.setMsgs(..)` I put a console statement for `successMessageList`.  When i add a message via a component I get an output that looks like this (**NOTE** the `observers: Array(1)` vs `observers: Array(0)` )

```
Subject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
```

But when I add a message via the `HttpInterceptor` I get this

```
Subject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
```

Any ideas on whats going on would be greatly appreciated!

**I am using Angular 5**

Comment: i think you need to need to push to `successMessages` which is a subject that will emit values for the component where as you are doing it local to the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was 100% user error.  In my `app.main` component I was declaring the `messageService` as a `provider` in the `@Component` so the service was not a shared singleton like i was expecting it to be.  After i removed that everything works as expected.